# Regex.Replace is stripping out pipe character

Tags: .net, regex

I have this function which is supposed to swap every spacial char like *á, ä*, etc for a normal one like *a*:

```
Private Function QuitaTildes(ByVal texto As String) As String
    Dim replace_a As Regex,
        replace_e As Regex,
        replace_i As Regex,
        replace_o As Regex,
        replace_u As Regex

    replace_a = New Regex("[á|à|ä|â]", RegexOptions.Compiled)
    replace_e = New Regex("[é|è|ë|ê]", RegexOptions.Compiled)
    replace_i = New Regex("[í|ì|ï|î]", RegexOptions.Compiled)
    replace_o = New Regex("[ó|ò|ö|ô]", RegexOptions.Compiled)
    replace_u = New Regex("[ú|ù|ü|û]", RegexOptions.Compiled)

    texto = replace_a.Replace(texto, "a")
    texto = replace_e.Replace(texto, "e")
    texto = replace_i.Replace(texto, "i")
    texto = replace_o.Replace(texto, "o")
    texto = replace_u.Replace(texto, "u")

    Return texto
End Function
```

The problem is, when `texto` is a regular expression pattern itself like `"one|twó|threé"` it's returning `"onetwothree"`, this is, it took out every `|` char, why? this text is in the replace string, not in the pattern so I shouldn't need to escape it.

Is there an option for regex to tell it to stop doing that?

(this function is done to save some pressor time so if I need to escape `|` char I won't save that much)

Thank you

Comment: As an aside, if you are doing this on many large strings, it will be significantly faster to loop through yourself and build a new string using a StringBuilder. Wait for performance to be a problem first, as always, but just an FYI.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that and maybe in the future it is a need to go for better performance, always though that regex engine was optimized for better performance than usual loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need | symbol.

```
replace_a = New Regex("[áàäâ]", RegexOptions.Compiled)
replace_e = New Regex("[éèëê]", RegexOptions.Compiled)
replace_i = New Regex("[íìïî]", RegexOptions.Compiled)
replace_o = New Regex("[óòöô]", RegexOptions.Compiled)
replace_u = New Regex("[úùüû]", RegexOptions.Compiled)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ditch `[]` in your pattern or `|` in your pattern.

`|` is used for `OR` but usually for example `your|you're` and can be used with groups `()`. The square brackets are also `OR` but for any ONE char inside of them.